# Changing the starting view on an existing project Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have an old project in Xcode and I want to change the RootViewController files (.m, .h, .xib - a TableViewController) with a normal ViewController!
Is it possible or I must restart a new project and import the old files?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible... but, umm, you've provided so little information it's really hard to answer this question in any meaningful way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how your project is set up.  But you may just need to include and change the controller linked to by the window and app delegate in your MainWindow.xib file.

Comment: hi guys!i've found a solution changing the structure of my .xib file and a little bit of code! not so hard ;) thx a lot!